# Unhooking a hook set with SetWindowsHookEx more than once crashes the hooked process

Tags: c++, winapi, 64-bit, setwindowshookex, unhookwindowshookex

I am trying to hook the keyboard and mouse events of a target application. 
I followed the SO question [How to hook external process with SetWindowsHookEx and WH_KEYBOARD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820804/how-to-hook-external-process-with-setwindowshookex-and-wh-keyboard), and the hooks are installed and uninstalled correctly the first time. However, after I uninstall the hook once and then install it again, trying to uninstall the hook the second time crashes the target application. The purpose of the hook is to monitor application idle time, so that I can do some tasks when the application is idle.
I apologize for the length of the question, but I tried to put in all the details that might help
Thanks

I need to be able to install and uninstall the hooks based on menu commands from a system tray icon. I have a console application [HookApp] which calls the install and uninstall methods in a DLL [HookDLL]. The console application also creates a window to handle menu events. I use the thread of the window to actually install and uninstall the hooks, because the same thread that installed the hook must uninstall it. The Console and the window both must be invisible. Only the system tray icon and its associated menu must be visible.
I start the hooking application from the command line with the parameters 
i. ProcessId of the target process
ii. Process Name
iii. Idle time [in seconds] -Idle time before starting the action in the DLL
I am wondering if the timer I start in the HookProcs is responsible for the crash.

Event Viewer Logs
Faulting application name: notepad.exe, version: 10.0.17134.1, time stamp: 0x9d4727c2
Faulting module name: HookDLL_x64.dll_unloaded, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5c31aabd
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000ba505
Faulting process id: 0x2bac

The exception code seems to suggest a memory access violation.

I have tried the following 
I.
a. Call the SendMessageTimeout API with HWND_BROADCAST from HookApp
b. Call the SendMessageTimeout API with HWND_BROADCAST from HookDLL
based on [Unloading DLL from all processes after unhooking global CBT hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164190/unloading-dll-from-all-processes-after-unhooking-global-cbt-hook/4076495#4076495)

II.
a. call FreeLibraryAndExitThread API in the DLLMain method on DLL_PROCESS_DETACH AND DLL_THREAD_DETACH -both together and singly
based on http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/42505-unloading-dll-crashes-exe/

III. Made the HookApp console and the window visible and hidden to see if it makes any difference

IV. Was unable to try the following because of 64 bit architecture
https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/programming-for-beginners/73377-unload-injected-dll-thread-process.html

Other Links I referred to
a. [Several programs crash when unhooking with UnhookWindowsHookEx()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713966/several-programs-crash-when-unhooking-with-unhookwindowshookex)
b. [How to correctly use SetWindowsHookEx & CallNextHookEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214022/how-to-correctly-use-setwindowshookex-callnexthookex)
c. [Unloading an Injected DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577117/unloading-an-injected-dll)
d. [FreeLibraryAndExitThread crashes program when unloading injected DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39780590/freelibraryandexitthread-crashes-program-when-unloading-injected-dll)

```
//Code in the DLL
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void install(unsigned long threadID,int _nIdleTime) {
    nIdleTime = _nIdleTime;
    Log(L"install proc called from app: _nIdleTime", _nIdleTime);
    hhKeyboard = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, KeyboardProc, hinst, threadID);
    hhMouse = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE, MouseProc, hinst, threadID);
    logger->Log("Install");
    logger->Log("Keyboard", (LONG)hhKeyboard);
    logger->Log("Mouse", (LONG)hhMouse);

}

//Uninstall the dll from the Target Process
DWORD WINAPI UnInjectDLLFromTarget() {
    uninstall();
    //DWORD_PTR dwResult = 0;
    //SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_NULL, 0, 0, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG | SMTO_NOTIMEOUTIFNOTHUNG, 1000, &dwResult);
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK KeyboardProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (code < 0) {

        return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    StartTimer();
    Beep(1000, 20);


    return CallNextHookEx(hhKeyboard, code, wParam, lParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MouseProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    if (code < 0) {

        return CallNextHookEx(0, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
    //  StartTimer();
        //Beep(1000, 20);

    return CallNextHookEx(hhMouse, code, wParam, lParam);
}
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(__in HINSTANCE hinstDLL, __in  DWORD fdwReason, __in  LPVOID lpvReserved) {


    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH || fdwReason==DLL_THREAD_DETACH) {
        FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hinstDLL, 0);
        return 0;
    }
}

//Code in the Application [HookApp]
Similar to  [But not exactly the same - It is a bit more involved because of the need to create the message pump and the menu event handling window]
 HINSTANCE hinst = LoadLibrary(_T("MyDLL.dll")); 

    if (hinst) {
        typedef void (*Install)(unsigned long);
        typedef void (*Uninstall)();

        Install install = (Install) GetProcAddress(hinst, "install");
        Uninstall uninstall = (Uninstall) GetProcAddress(hinst, "uninstall");

        install(threadID);

        Sleep(20000);

        uninstall();
    }
```

1. SendMessageTimeout in the DLL [HookDLL] method Uninstall immediately crashes the application
2. SendMessageTimeout in the application [HookApp] doesnt appear to do anything useful.
3. FreeLibraryAndExitThread does not appear to do anything useful.
   However, with 2 and 3, I think I am able to install the hook for the second time. Without them, the first unhook crashes the application.
4. I was unable to try the suggestion using assembly language inline because of 64 bit architecture.

Please help.

Comment: You haven't shown the `uninstall()` function.

Comment: `FreeLibraryAndExitThread(hinstDLL, 0);` this is your fatal error. code wrong from all view. you not need it at all. the dll will be auto free when you uninstall hook

Comment: no any problems with unload dll - this will be done when you call `UnhookWindowsHookEx`. you must never call direct `FreeLibrary` yourself. link from msdn wrong or unclear - system is call `FreeLibrary` for hook dll just when thread receiver first message after call `UnhookWindowsHookEx`. call `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` at all fatal and senseless in all case

Comment: so you need`UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhMouse); UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhKeyboard); PostThreadMessageW(threadID, WM_NULL, 0, 0);`  - all. you nothing need todo inside dll entry point, and not need it here at all

Answer (score 2):

for uninstall hook and unload your dll all what you need - call `UnhookWindowsHookEx` for every hook handle obtained by a previous call to `SetWindowsHookEx`. all. you not need call `FreeLibrary[AndExitThread]` yourself. system auto call `FreeLibrary` on your hook dll after `UnhookWindowsHookEx` callend, when first (any) message will be received by target application thread and this thread call `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage`. so for just unload your dll after several `UnhookWindowsHookEx` - you need post message to thread, for which you install hook. if you do this for concrete single thread (`dwThreadId`) - you need `PostThreadMessageW(dwThreadId, WM_NULL, 0, 0);` - system yourself call `FreeLibrary` ( called from `user32!__ClientFreeLibrary` which called from `ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcher` - called inside `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage` when thread (or it window) got any message)

call `FreeLibrary` from dll for yourself - always error - if assume dll will be unloaded by this call - to where we return after call ? to unloaded place. call `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` exist sense in some cases, but only from thread, which you create yourself. call `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` from dll entry point at all fatal error - you kill not self thread, thread which you kill - hold critical section (loader lock) inside which called dll entry point - so fatal error. and at all absolute senseless call here - if you say receive `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` this mean that dll already in unload process. `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` - arbitrary point, why and how many time you try call unload for self here ? exit thread while holding process wide critical section without release it. fatal error.

also *because the same thread that installed the hook must uninstall it.* - this is not true. another thread from also can do this.

also `StartTimer();` in your code look like suspicious here. what this code is do ? are and where you cancel timer ?

Comment: I commented out the StartTimer() method call in the HookProc, and now it doesnt crash even after several installs and uninstalls of the hook. So I added a call to StopTimer() in Uninstall. It works great now.Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the Unhook api call unloaded the dll, and the timer started a thread which tried to access memory of code in the dll, leading to the crash.  So disabling the timer stopped that thread. So the crashes stopped

Comment: @SagarKapadia - if you still use `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` from dll entry point crash is guaranteed